# Prevent Visual Studio debugging breaking on an apparent "unhandled exception"

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Please consider this short console app code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Action a = () =>
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Oops");
        };

        var ar = a.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            a.EndInvoke(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("No message");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When run Visual Studio will break on the `throw` complaining that its unhandled.  When executed outside of the debugger the code does what I expect (displays "Oops").

How do I convince Visual Studio to allow the code to execute as it would do in the real world?

Comment: If the lambda was a method you could apply the [DebuggerNonUserCode attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx) to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @dtb: Thats well worth placing in an answer, but I'd like to see an alternative that allows me to retain the lambda.

Comment: just observation: Visual Studio complains when `ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` is called, not when `a.EndInvoke(ar)` which is within try.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Thats not what I'm experiencing with this exact code.  Visual Studio is stopping on the `throw` line.

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, untick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.

Comment: @Hans: That was mine first thought. But it doesn't help (it was unchecked btw)

Comment: @Hans: Thanks but the Thrown box is already unticked.  If you slap the above code in a new console app do you experience the same behaviour as I am?

Comment: @Anthony: I mean that if you debug step by step then exception is hit _before_ try block is entered.

Comment: I don't, never seen it do this either and have exercised this many times.  The debugger stopping on the first chance exception notification is the only explanation.  What do you actually see in the Output window?

Comment: @Hans: Yes I see in the output window I'm seeing "A first chance exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred ....".  What does that mean?

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Yes that is what I see but in the real world that exception would be kept in some form of "limbo" until `EndInvoke` is called at which point the exception would be thrown from `EndInvoke`.  However when VS debugger is attached its not getting that far.

Comment: what happens when you just click the run button when the exception appears?

Comment: @Chris: Visual Studio breaks on the `throw` line.

Comment: Yes, but if you click the run button after it stops on the throw line, it should continue on and you should get your "Oops" method on the console.  It did for me, when I tried it.

Comment: @Chris: Thats great but really annoying when thats what I __want__ it to do when I'm testing. I don't wanna have to keep telling VS "That error is ok carry on as normal", every time this occurs.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I'm getting the same thing, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the [DebuggerNonUserCode attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx) to a method to hide it from the debugger.

Comment: How would you put such an attribute on an anonymous delegate?